# If an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ has n pairwise distinct eigenvalues, are the eigenvectors of $A$ and ${A}^{2}$ the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following statement and want to find out is it true or false:
If an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ has n pairwise distinct eigenvalues, then the eigenvectors of $A$ and ${A}^{2}$ are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Try $\pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & -1\cr}$.

Comment: Thanks, was looking forward some example